# Virtual Host in Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, virtualhost, tomcat8

I want to map a domain `mydomain.com` to an application. I added a `<Host>` entry into `server.xml`, but when I go to `www.mydomain.com` it shows the Tomcat start page instead of my application.

server.xml:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
   <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>

  <Host name="localhost" autoDeploy="true" unpackWARs="true" appBase="webapps">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" pattern="%h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b" suffix=".txt" prefix="localhost_access_log" directory="logs"/>
  </Host>


  <Host name="mydomain.com" autoDeploy="true" unpackWARs="true" appBase="webapps">
    <Alias>www.mydomain.com</Alias>
    <Context privileged="true" debug="0" docBase="/opt/tomcat/webapps/MyDomain" path=""/>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" pattern="%h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b" suffix=".txt" prefix="localhost_access_log." directory="logs" resolveHosts="false"/>
  </Host>

</Engine>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined two hosts with the same deployment directory `webapps`

If you want `localhost` to be different than `mydomain` define two deployment directories and rename the root context war to ROOT.war. it is not recommended to use `<Context` tag

```
<Host name="localhost" autoDeploy="true" unpackWARs="true" appBase="webapps">
```

```
<Host name="www.mydomain.com" autoDeploy="true" unpackWARs="true" appBase="mydomain">
</Host>
```

You do not need `alias` since the host name contains the domain name. All others requests coming from a DNS entry different to `www.mydomain.com` will be served by `localhost`

If `localhost` and `www.mydomain.com` are the same, then you just need a `<Host` and deploy a `ROOT.war`

```
 <Host name="localhost" autoDeploy="true" unpackWARs="true" appBase="webapps">
 </Host>
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to map my applications like this in the server.xml file.

Delete the host entry you added and inside the host entry you had from the start put this:

```
<Context path="/" docBase="yourApp">
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
<Context path="/ROOT" docBase="ROOT">
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

Dont forget to change yourApp